# Mirroring web server in different port

Tags: port-forwarding, port, web, mirroring, forwarding

I have a local web server which is accessible from the Internet through port 3333. I used port forwarding to achieve this. And now I am planning to develop a solution (possible network configuration or simply develop a web application) to serve it over other web server but in port 80 (standard) - mirroring in different port.

To better explain my requirements, basically I have a web server running in LAN, just name it localname and it is accessible from the Internet through `http://localname:3333`. Now I want to setup other server (physically separated server) and I want to make `http://publicname:80/` to display `http://localname:3333/` and the web application must be able to run. I don't know what is the term for this (is it mirroring?), since I am not a network administration person.

Thanks, I hope I can explain my requirements clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just portfoward 80(public) to 3333(internal LAN)?
Then from the internet all requests to port 80 on your IP address would be sent to your router and from there to your server on the LAN on port 3333.